# The term 'Get-AzSynapseSqlPool' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook, azure-synapse

I was tryng to upscale synapse using azure runbook in powershell but the commands listed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/get-azsynapsesqlpool?view=azps-7.1.0#code-try-3 are not recognisable with the error "The term 'Get-AzSynapseSqlPool' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
| function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the
| name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
| again."
can anyone help?

Comment: Did you install the module (Az.Synapse)?

Comment: In the Shared Resources of your automation account  ,do you have the  Az.Synapse module ?If not , add a module from the local machine  and import it to the runbook in cmdlet using  ***Import-module -name Az.Synapse***

Comment: thank you so much ,it was a silly mistake i did

Comment: can you help me in commands of upscaling service tier of synapse sql pool in powershell,i cant find that

Answer (score 1):

Go to Portal =>Automation Accounts =>Your Shared Resource =>Runbook
Check if you have Az.Synapse module.
If not , add a module from the local machine and import it to the runbook using

```
 Import-module -name Az.Synapse
```

Command for upscaling service tier of synapse sql pool

```
Set-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "resourcegroupname" -DatabaseName "mySampleDataWarehouse" -ServerName "sqlpoolservername" -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "DW300c"
```

Please refer [Updates a Synapse Analytics SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/update-azsynapsesqlpool?view=azps-7.1.0)  and [Scale compute for dedicated SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/quickstart-scale-compute-powershell#s)  for more information.